# PerformenceProgessBar and ObservableCollection

Tags: silverlight, collections, windows-phone-7

I have an ObservableCollection that gets data from a foreach. The UI updates great when changes are made to the collection, but there is a lag as the collection size starts to increase in size. I have about 500+ items in my collection that get deleted, reordered and added. But I've noticed that there is a definite lag between when the changes are made and when they are reflected in the UI. The example below is just a simple one. Obviously, the progress bar won't be on for long in this case (fraction of a second), but the point I'm making is that the UI won't reflect the changes I've made for many, many noticeable seconds after the progress bar is stopped below. What event can I capture or implement in my object  that will allow me to add code that updates the progress bar while the ObservableCollection is being pushed to the UI? Or does someone want to send me a "DealWithIt" dog picture :)

```
a_progressbar.IsIndeterminate = true;
foreach (Group<SomeItem> sortedItem in sortedItems)
{
    OList.Add(sortedItem);
}
a_progressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;
```

**Update** Here is the code I used to make it work.

```
            _dataBinder = new BackgroundWorker();
            _dataBinder.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DataBinderWork);
            _dataBinder.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(DataBinderComplete);

...

        private void DataBinderComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                a_progressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            });
        }

        private void DataBinderWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => LotsOfWork());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good job for the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) component.  The component will allow you to perform expensive operations in a background thread so your UI won't hang; meanwhile, the UI thread can be notified via events so it knows when the work has completed.

**Update**:

I must have misunderstood the question.  If your question is about a list in your UI that is bound to the `ObservableCollection` being slow to update when adding a bunch of items, one thing you could attempt to do is to build a *new* `ObservableCollection`, filling it with the data you need, then assigning the new collection to the UI.

I've had problems with `ObservableCollection` in the past because it raises an event every time an item is added, which makes the UI responsiveness poor.  My workaround was to create a sub-class of the collection where you could do an `AddRange` which only raised one event, but simply building a new collection that isn't bound to the UI then binding it after it's been populated is another option.

Comment: My UI isn't hanging though, I can move around normally. The data just takes a while to show up. Maybe I'm wrong. I am doing all this work in an ASync call from WebClient. So there shouldn't be any blocking work here, especially since I'm using Observable. Maybe updating the list with so many objects is what is causing it and really what I should be doing is limiting the # of items. I will do some more UI testing to see if I can prove or disprove this.

Comment: OK, maybe I mis-read your question.  You said "What event can I capture or implement in my object that will allow me to add code that updates the progress bar while the ObservableCollection is being pushed to the UI?" which I interpreted to mean that your progress bar wasn't drawing.  Are you saying you want your `ListBox` or other UI items that are bound to the `ObservableCollection` to update as you add items?

Comment: Ahh, I added a background worker and that did a good job of making the UI work a little better. I like the idea of using AddRange to make the event fire once rather than 500 times :) Thanks for the idea. I didn't even think about it because it was in the async download event.

Comment: I have a question about when the runtime actually executes the databind for Observable Collections. To me it seems like it's not instant, like it waits until the entire transaction is complete before it commits the change in the data. Maybe i'm wrong and it's happening too fast, but if i had a .Clear() a foreach .Add(), wouldn't i see the list clear and then add one at a time? becuase it doesn't look like that at all.

Comment: Whenever the data change events fire, the binding engine marks the items bound to the changed data as dirty, and then the actual redrawing of the UI happens during the next graphical update frame.  I believe the default framerate for Silverlight is 50 FPS.

Comment: I implemented an AddRange method on my collection as seen [here](http://www.damonpayne.com/post/2010/03/04/AddRange-for-ObservableCollection-in-Silverlight-3.aspx). It sped up the data binding enough to where it performs well.

Answer (score 0):

A big warning against the use of ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate - it takes more than 60% of the CPU resources and can have disastrous impact in some cases. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Animations.aspx?msg=3811440#xx3811440xx) for more info.

Comment: Wow that article made me sad :( Basically I need to choose between having a jerky progress bar or having my phone run 200 degrees and eat my battery in 20 seconds :)